# Erro ao criar cookie json com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Estou tentando criar um simples cookie com um valor da key em json, mas estou recebendo do navegador isso(clique na foto):

[image: Print do navegador]

[Esse é o plugin que estou utilizando](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v1.5.1)

> Código, segue abaixo:

```
 $.cookie("gavetaMilagres", '{"sub_key_1":"sub_value_1", "sub_key_2":"sub_value_2"}');
```

Gostaria que ficasse , por exemplo, asssim:

```
"{\"time\": 1511524234\054 \"177.42.157.224\": 18881}"
```

Mas está assim:

```
%22%7B%5C%22sub_key_1%5C%22%3A%5C%22sub_value_1%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22sub_key_2%5C%22%3A%5C%22sub_value_2%5C%22%7D%22
```

Comment: Tem que ver como vc tah montando esse cookie. No exemplo de código vc só colocou variáveis: `$.cookie("gavetaMilagres", '{"sub_key_1":"sub_value_1", "sub_key_2":"sub_value_2"}');`

Comment: Essa é a informação e o resultado é o que ta aí.